# ASP.NET - Static Variables & State Machines -Will one user affect another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iterator, yield-return

I have implemented some functionality in C# using the `yield` statement with the function returning an IEnumerable.

My question is that if this function is a static function in a static class, does it implicitly hold anything as a state machine that would affect more than one user or does the iterator hold *everything* relating to the state? (Static members are application wide.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not.  The created `IEnumerable<T>` will be of a type which contains no additional static data.  It is possible for it to reference static information but only if you explicitly access it from within the iterator

For example.

```
public static class Utils {
  public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) {
    for (var i = start; i <= count; i++) {
      yield return i;
    }
  }
}
```

Roughly translates into

```
public static class Utils {
  private class RangeIterator : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerator<int> {
    ... 
    // iterator state machine
  }
  public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) {
    return new RangeIterator(start, count);
  }
}
```